FLIR Lepton on RaspBerry Pi 5
I have a FLIR Lepton conected to a raspberry pi 5. I nned to start it from a python file.
I followed the groupgets github page to start the camera.
cd into /LeptonModule/software/raspberrypi_video.
Then run:

qmake && make,
sudo sh -c "echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor"
./raspberrypi_video -tl 3
And it Works fine. So I went and read a little about subprocess and whatnot and wrote up a simple script, and I simply do not understand why it is not working:

import subprocess
import os

def start_camera():

directory = '/LeptonModule/software/raspberrypi_video'
command = 'qmake && make'
command1 = 'sudo sh -c "echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor"'
command2 = './raspberrypi_video -tl 3'

os.chdir(directory)

process = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
process1 = subprocess.run(command1, shell=True, check=True)
process2 = subprocess.run(command1, shell=True, check=True)

print("Camera Started")

if __name__ == "__main__":
start_camera()

When I run the file, it simply exits witth code 0. The camera window does not pop up, nothing else pops up. What amI doing Wrong?

first you could use print() to see exit code for every process. Second: it may need to use /full/path for every element - command, script, output file, etc.

as for me command qmake && make is for compiling some code and you can do it only once - and you don't have to run it again, so you can skip it. As for me second command send some value to device and maybe it can be used only once - and maybe you don't have to run it - but I'm not sure. So maybe you should run only ./raspberrypi_video -tl 3. But if you needs only one command then there is no need to create script. BTW: it would be much simpler to put all commands directly in text command and add in first line #!/usr/bin/bash and run it as bash script

BTW: in question you could add link to groupgets github page.

if you have some problems with Raspberry then you can also ask on similar portal for Raspberry Pi and on official forum Raspberry Pi

You run subprocess with check=True so it doesn't raise error when there is a problem
and you have to check value(s) in process.returncode
And subprocess may return error number in returcode but it doesn't stop python script and script can return exit code 0. You would have to use exit(1) or sys.exit(1) to get exit code 1.
So first you could check
print(process.returncode)
print(process1.returncode)
print(process2.returncode)

But I think you don't need some of commands.
Command qmake && make probably compiles code and you have to use it only once - so you don't have to use it again and you can skip it in script.
Command sudo sh -c "echo performance > /sys/device/ ... probably changes some settings in device and probably this device may remember it - so you don't have to use it  again and you can skip it in script.
So you need to use only chdir and './raspberrypi_video -tl 3'
import subprocess
import os

def start_camera():
    directory = '/LeptonModule/software/raspberrypi_video'
    command = './raspberrypi_video -tl 3'

    os.chdir(directory)

    process = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
    print("returncode:", process.returncode)
    
    print("Camera Started")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_camera()

But frankly it is simpler to put it directly in file with #!/bin/bash in first line, and make it executable (using command chmod +x your_script) and you may run it as any other script.
your_script.sh (you can also use name without extension .sh)
#!/bin/bash 

cd /LeptonModule/software/raspberrypi_video
./raspberrypi_video -tl 3

Raspberry may have your ~/bin in variable PATH so you can create folder bin in your home folder and put this script in this folder and then you may run it without using full path.

Of course you can put #!/usr/bin/env python3 in Python script, use chmod +x to make it executable, and put script in ~/bin and then you may also run it as script ./your_script without writing python console. (script's name can be without extension .py)

Thanks!That is very Helpful, you were write I did not need qmake or the other command.
